# I Get 'Import error : No module named MYSQLdb' in python 2.7. I've tried everything from the other similar thread

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

The error:

> import MySQLdb
>   ImportError: No module named MySQLdb.

Particulars:

- OS is Ubuntu 14.04
- python 2.7.10 and is the default
- MySQL 5.5.43

What I've tired:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
>   
> sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Changing MySQL version. I was on 5.6.smthn

> easy_install MySQL-python
>   
> pip install MySQL-python

I'm not getting errors in the install of MySQLdb but the above error is thrown from within python and if I run it in a .py when I try to import MySQLdb.

MySQLdb is also conspicuously missing from the list of modules when you type into python.

> help('modules')

I would really appreciate the help. It's been driving me nuts.

Comment: Is it possible that it is installing MySQLdb to another version of python?

Comment: Isn't 2.7.6 the default version of python2 in 14.04? do you really have 2.7.10? if so, how?

Comment: I installed 2.7.10 because that was the version that is being used for a course im doing. By default i meant when I type 'python --version' it tells me 'python 2.7.10' and when I open python in the terminal it comes up with 'python 2.7.10 (default, etc.' I didn't know it came with 2.7 already. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I solved it. In case anyone else googles this problem. My OS install was very recent so I just installed the OS again and started from scratch using the stock everything. I assume the issue is that the mysqldb installers install to the python (and perhaps the mysql) version that came with the OS. If this is the case then there should be a relatively simple manual install you can do to fix this without going with the nuclear option of reinstalling the OS. I have no idea what exactly this entails since I'm really new with linux.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble. My python is 2.7.12 . I tried with pip and pip3 but none of them worked. 
Try `sudo pip2 install MySQL-python`.

It worked for me.